# Find the integration $\int_{1}^{\infty} \cos (x^2) dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the integration 
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \cos (x^2) dx$$

I tried using substitute of $x^2=t$, but I get nothing pls help

Comment: idk how to do this without complex analysis... i might not even know how to do it with complex analysis.. i know how to do from 0 to ∞

Comment: There's no answer without using some special function - for example, the Fresnel integral.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more generally, 
$$ \int_a^\infty \cos(x^2)\; dx = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}- \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} FresnelC\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} a\right)$$
where FresnelC is the [Fresnel cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html).  I'm not aware of any special "closed-form" value for $a=1$.

Comment: Ok, but how can we say the integral is convergent?

Comment: Change of variables $t=x^2$ and then consider an alternating series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{(n-1/2)\pi}^{(n+1/2)\pi} \frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\; dt $$